# Array being overriden at each iteration of for loop

Tags: php

How can I store changing variables ($i,$j) in the info array ,So that it contains all the values not just the last?

```
<?php
    for($i=0,$j=0;$i<3;$i++,$j++){
        $members=array($i,$j);
        $info=array();
        foreach ($members as $k) { 
            $info[]=$k;
        }
    }    
    print_r($info);
?>
```

Comment: Please try and explain in plain english what you are trying to achieve, the code above is meaningless without context.

Comment: Note that simply declaring `$info` outside the loop would fix your imediate issue, but im sure the whole problem could be solved in a better way if you explain it

Comment: the array is storing just the last value (2,2) i want it to store((0,0),(1,1),(2,2))

Answer (score 1):

Just put array variable `$info` to outside of loop, It is being overwrite in each iteration.

```
<?php
$info=array();
for($i=0,$j=0;$i<3;$i++,$j++){
$members=array($i,$j);

foreach ($members as $k) { 
    $info[]=$k;
}
}
print_r($info);
?>
```

check your output : https://eval.in/608707

I don't know you purpose, but you can also do it by many ways

1. https://eval.in/608744
2. https://eval.in/608721

Comment: The code is still pointless -why bother with `$members` and the innermost loop at all?

Comment: Yes, or even https://eval.in/608745 as the `$j` counter is also useless. Probably the op has some reason for it, but without elaborating, this is unknown, so no decent answer can be made

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done

```
<?php
    $info=array();
    for($i=0,$j=0;$i<3;$i++,$j++){
    $info=array_merge($info,array(array($i,$j)));

    }
    print_r($info);
    ?>
```

Comment: Of `$info = array_map(null, range(0, 2), range(0, 2));`